# Run RabbitMQ without default user being created

Tags: rabbitmq

I am running single RabbitMQ instance. Because of uniformity, all queues, exchanges, bindings and users will be created from `definitions.json` file.

**My config:**

```
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

However RabbitMQ also as default creates user named `guest` with password `guest`. Even if this user is not specified in `definitions.json` or config file.

**Problem:**

How can I setup RabbitMQ **WITHOUT** creating default user?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#default-state) regarding the `guest` user: "_If a blank node [imports definitions on boot](https://www.rabbitmq.com/definitions.html#import-on-boot-nuances), this default user will not be created._" Are you doing that (it seems as if you are)? But it seems you are seeing different behavior...? (Just a comment because I have not tried this specific approach myself.)

Comment: If you already created the node, and then performed this load from `definitions.json`, at a later step (not the first ever boot) then just delete the `guest` user.

Comment: @andrewJames Docs you mentioned were correct. It was mistanke on my part - Config file contained more details which I did not mention.

Can you please write this as an answer so I can accept it? I think little pieces like this, easily accessible from google can save some documentation reading time.

Comment: Thank you, but you are the one who got it working. I think you should answer this one yourself. (All I did was write a comment - and I never tested it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As andrewJames pointed out, RabbitMQ user, which must be specified in conf file is not created, if there is `management.load_definitions` specified.

**What was the confusion here?**

By default, this basic user is specified, like this:

```
default_user = guest
default_pass = guest
```

Even if this is still specified, rabbitmq will just ignore this and create users purely based on definitions file. While this may be harmless, specified default user and password will still make some security checks to scream.